# The non empty set of accumulation points of a bounded linear operator is the spectrum of another operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space, and let   $T \in L(X)$ such that the  set of accumulation points of  $T$ is non empty, i-e $\mbox{acc}\,\sigma(T)\neq 0.$\
Is there a Banach space $Y$ and an operator $S_{T} \in L(Y)$ (which is a function of $T$)  with $\sigma(S_{T})=\mbox{acc}\,\sigma(T)$ and  $\mbox{iso}\,\sigma(S_{T})=\emptyset.$

Comment: A subset of the corresponding field, real or complex, is the spectrum of a bounded linear operator if and only if it is compact.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for how can I remove isolated points from an operator $T$ to find an operator $S_ {T}$ which is a function of $T$ with $\sigma(S_{T})=\mbox{acc}\,\sigma(T)$ and $\mbox{iso}\,\sigma(S_{T})=\emptyset.$

Comment: Maybe I don't understand this question correctly, but any diagonal compact operator K on Hilbert space H has only 0 as an accumulation point, but the only function of K which removes the isolated points is 0, and 0 is an isolated point of the spectrum of the 0 operator, with the eigenspace = H.